# Laravel Database notification id generation, need to stop this behavior

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am using Database notifications with oracle database, I am dealing with views and procedures. I need to customize DatabaseNotification class, because it is generating an id for every record. I need to make database stop the notification system, I traced the generation of id it is in sendNow function of NotificationSender class, it generates notificationId like $notificationId = Str::uuid()->toString(); in line 102, then set the notification id to id in the function sendToNotifiable with this code if (! $notification->id) { $notification->id = $id; } all i need is to stop this behavior, is there a way to do so ?

I commented these snippets of code in the core Laravel code ? i need more convenient solution or what should i do?